# Querying from sqlite and parsing data into google map

Tags: php, sqlite, google-maps, parsing, google-maps-api-3

i have a question regarding exporting data from sqlite using php script and parsing it into google map.

I have did up a query script on php but i am unsure how can i parse it into my google map. I did tried searching around but i am not a very technical person thus i am having problem implementing it.

This is the result of my php query

```
    array(18) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["mac"]=>
    string(17) "00:60:64:af:b9:be"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(-27.5759707)
    ["lon"]=>
    float(153.0646822)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["mac"]=>
    string(17) "00:60:64:af:b9:be"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(114.29077148438)
    ["lon"]=>
    float(30.566990873153)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["mac"]=>
    string(17) "10:60:64:af:b9:be"
    ["lat"]=>
    float(-110.390625)
    ["lon"]=>
    float(59.175928249271)
  }
```

This is my current google map script which is parsing data from a json file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
//createMarker function
function createMarker(latLng, title, content,icon) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          title: title,
        });




//Onclick listener(mouseover)
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

}

// initialization function (focus location ,map type and zoom level)
        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.48939, 153.012772),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);
//reading location file
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = '\week.json';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }



    //eqfeed call back will take result array and loop through each marker
    window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
      var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {

        var wifin = results.features[i]; 
        var coords = wifin.geometry.coordinates; 
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]); 
        bounds.extend(latLng);

        var content ="<div style='height:100px; width:300px; overflow:auto;'><table>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiMacAddress</th><td>"+wifin.properties.WifiMacAddress+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>SSID</th><td>"+wifin.properties.SSID+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>SignalStrength</th><td>"+wifin.properties.SignalStrength+"</td></tr>";
        content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiFrequency</th><td>"+wifin.properties.WifiFrequency+"</td></tr>";
        content +="</table>";

        createMarker(latLng,wifin.WifiMacAddress,content);
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


      </script>
```